# Newbie Hibernate Question: HQL to Load single child object given the parent object and a secondary key on child object

Tags: sql, hibernate, join, hql, lazy-evaluation

Sorry if this is very basic as a question....but I can't my head around the HQL syntax from the examples I have seen....

I have parent class ('File') which has a one-to-many relationship with a child class ('segment').

I have an instance loaded of the 'File' Parent class : I have a secondary key ('segment_number') ready - I just want to fetch single 'Segment' instance from the DB. (I don't want hibernate to fetch the whole Set of child Segments back, as this class contains a CLOB field.

What is the HQL for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like

```
String hql =  "from Segment where segment_number = :segment_number and file = :file";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql).
                 setParameter('segment_number', segment_number).
                 setParameter('file', file, File.class);
List result = query.list()
```

Comment: Pretty much correct -thanks ! I had to change the single quotes to doubles and remove the final argument File.class to get it to work for me. Cheers!